# Microsoft Visio arrow symbol

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-visio

Does anyone know if I can get the following arrow symbol in Visio?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Just add normal line ("Dynamic connector", "Right-angle connector") with an angle. Then you can move angles to make this line with CTRL key when dragging with Mouse.

2) Add // as label to your line and move it over your line. :-)